# How to manage the space between components in angular

Tags: html, css, angular, twitter-bootstrap

Question updated*

I have the following page and I want to delete the space between navbar and "Add new set"
I am using the template from https://bootswatch.com/4/flatly/bootstrap.css

[image]

In angular I have them as separate components:

```
<div>
  <app-navbar></app-navbar>
  <app-new-set></app-new-set>
</div>
```

The navbar component:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <div class="container">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

The add set component:

```
<div class="container">
  <h4 align="center">Add new set</h4>
  <div class="row">
   ...
  </div>
</div>
```

When I inspected with devtools, it doesn't appear where is the space from, it doesn't come from the components.

[image]

Comment: open devtools and inspect you code. without demo it's impossible to answer

Comment: It's hard to answer without inspecting the source code. @dfsq is correct, it's impossible to answer.

Comment: @dfsq I inspected with devtools and it seems that the space doesn't come from any of the elements.  Can it be because the navbar and add-new-set are different components in Angular4?

Comment: This doesn't really answer your question directly, but just as a general word of advice to make your Angular code cleaner and easier to style and understand: rather than using div wrappers / containers around your components, you can accomplish the same thing by using the CSS :host selector - which would apply the styling directly to the <app-navbar> element or whatever component you use it in. Doing this might make it a bit easier to troubleshoot your issue as you eliminate a lot of redundant divs

Comment: Please check if you have any margin on top of <h4> heading 'Add new set'. If yes, please remove it.

Comment: "display: flex" should do the trick